# boost::date_time (boost-145) using a 64-bit uint with microsec calculations, without truncation

Tags: c++, datetime, boost

I am using date_time to abstract away platform peculiarities. and I need to produce a 64-bit microsec resolution uint64_t which will be used in serialization. I do not understand what is going wrong below.

```
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
#include <boost/cstdint.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace boost::posix_time;
using boost::uint64_t;

ptime UNIX_EPOCH(boost::gregorian::date(1970,1,1));

int main() {
    ptime current_time = microsec_clock::universal_time();

    std::cout << "original time: "<< current_time << std::endl;

    long microsec_since_epoch = ((current_time -UNIX_EPOCH).total_microseconds());

    ptime output_ptime = UNIX_EPOCH + microseconds(microsec_since_epoch);
        std::cout << "Deserialized time : " << output_ptime << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Microsecond output: " << microsec_since_epoch << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Microsecond to second arithmetic: "
        << microsec_since_epoch/(10*10*10*10*10*10) << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Microsecond to tiume_duration, back to microsecond : " <<
        microseconds(microsec_since_epoch).total_microseconds() << std::endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output I get.

```
original time: 2010-Dec-17 09:52:06.737123
Deserialized time : 1970-Jan-16 03:10:41.577454
Microsecond output: 1292579526737123
Microsecond to second arithmetic: 1292579526
Microsecond to tiume_duration, back to microsecond : 1307441577454
```

When I switch to using `total_seconds()` and +`seconds(..)` The problems dissapear --i.e., input changes to:

```
2010-Dec-15 18:26:22.606978
2010-Dec-15 18:26:22
```

date_time claims to use a 64-bit type internally, and `2^64÷ (10^6×3600×24×365) ~= 584942` even `2^60÷ (10^6×3600×24×365) ~= 36558`.

The opening lines from wikipedia have this to say about Posix time

> Unix time, or POSIX time, is a system
>   for describing points in time, defined
>   as the number of seconds elapsed since
>   midnight Coordinated Universal Time
>   (UTC) of January 1, 1970

Why is such Massive truncation going on 40 years down the line ?

How do I use the full 64-bit space with microsecond resolution using boost::date_time ?

**--edit1 in response to hans--**

The post has been changed to reflect the integer output of the duration.total_microseconds() part. Note 1292576572566904÷(10^6×3600×24×365) ~= 40.98 years. The output from seconds has not been updated.

**--edit2--**
Downscaling the microseconds to seconds before the "deserialization" step, also works well. This approach solved my problem,I only need the microsecond resolution at creation, and I can live without it at deserialization.

I do still want to know the what and why of the problem.

Comment: I'm curious too since I intend to also write something that uses 64-bit microsecond resolution time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a problem with the microseconds() not be ing able to handle such a large microseconds input. The following snippit is a fix to this problem:

```
#define MICROSEC 1000000

uint64_t sec_epoch = microsec_since_epoch / MICROSEC;
uint64_t mod_micro_epoch= microsec_since_epoch % MICROSEC;

ptime new_method = UNIX_EPOCH  + seconds(sec_epoch) + microseconds(mod_micro_epoch);

std::cout << "Deserialization with new method: " << new_method << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

The return type for total_microseconds() is `tick_type`, not long.  Looks like you're compiling this with a compiler that has a 32-bit long type.  Much to small to store 40 years worth of microseconds.

Comment: 64-bit server ubuntu :/. pluss the integer that comes out from the total_microseconds(); is actually correct. 40.98 years worth of microseconds. I will modify the program above to illustrate this when I get into work. I wouldn't be suprised if things get truncated on the epoch + microsecond part.

Comment: Updated my post to show you what is coming out of total_microseconds.